# React TypeScript Input Paste Event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a component and currently I'm watching for events on `input` and `textarea` with a typed event via `InputEvent: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>`

I'm having trouble determining which event type would be fired when pasting input into these elements. Would I be reduced to using `any` for this or do they have an event that would be relevant when pasting input?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know it has been a while since you asked, but I ran into the same problem today. Fixed it with:

```
event: React.ClipboardEvent
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to handle the paste event:
You can use `onPaste` event in `input`.

```
paste(e){
    // e.target.value: this is prev value before paste.
  }
...
<input type="text" onPaste={this.paste} />
```

Comment: Thank you, the question was more centered around what the event should be "typed" as. This may help someone though!